# Do I apply delta method correctly?

Tags: modeling, delta-method

I'm no mathematician, so please consider the whole explanation as a subject to criticism and optimization.

I'm trying to build a model and calculate an estimate of error variance for the following problem.
Consider a point in 3D, a ray coming out of it towards some plane, and the point of intersection of this ray and the plane. Now the measurements contain the following errors:
1) the plane slope error $\alpha$. I decided to make it isotropic for simplicity and describe it by the angle of aperture of the hypothetical cone, which is drawn by all possible inclinations of the plane's normal vector.
2) the plane shift error $\delta$. This is the parallel shift error (from the fourth member of the plane equation).
3) the direction error $\phi$. I can also be modelled with a cone with an axis coinciding to the error-free ray and with given angular aperture angle.

Let's assume that all three random variables are normally distributed and have zero mean (the cones are the same with +- angle aperture, and the shift can go up and down from the error-free state). From some other modelings I also have the estimates of the variances of the three variables.

Now I would like to get the the variance of the error in intersection point positioning as a function of relative direction of the ray and position the plane. Of course this error is a random function of the three errors, too, so I have to use the multivariate delta method to estimate the variance of the error given the variances of the input errors. To apply it, I need the gradient vector of the function in the point (0,0,0) as all three variables are zero-mean. To estimate it, I subsequently do the following.
1) Compute the $f(\epsilon,0,0)/\epsilon$ which can be thought of intersection of a slightly inclined plane with no erroneous shift with a error-free ray, which gives one point.
2) Compute the $f(0,\epsilon,0)/\epsilon$ which gives the intersection of un-inclined, but slightly shifted plane with a ray, which again gives one single point.
3) Compute the $f(0,0,\epsilon)/\epsilon$ which is the intersection of a correct plane with a cone which gives an ellipse, from which I can find the longest distance to the "correct" point.

Now, having the gradient vector J and the covariance matrix $\Sigma=diag(\sigma(\alpha)^2,\sigma(\delta)^2,\sigma(\phi)^2)$, I can get the error variance as $\sigma(f)^2 = J^T*\Sigma*J$

I do actually get some more or less acceptable values as a result, and even the functional dependence of $f$ on the relative position of the ray and the plane is modeled somehow. But I would like to understand how accurate is this modeling and how viable is my modeling in general. So my questions:

1) if the function $f(\alpha,\delta,\phi)$ is somewhat non-linear, is delta method prone to significant errors? Does it approximate $f$ to be linear with slope $J(0,0,0)$?
2) it seems very unintuitive that in all real cases, when $\alpha,\delta,\phi\neq0$ the error is modeled with an intersection of the cone and a number of shifted and inlined planes, for calculations with delta method I only have to use degenerate cases, as I need the gradient in the vicinity of the $(0,0,0)$ point.
3) does the model and its parameterization look convincing in the least possible order of approximation? I also have some other similar modelings, so I would like to know if my approach is viable.

Thanks in advance.